# Any way to programmatically wrap a .NET WebService with a SoapExtension?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

Basically, I'm trying to tap into the Soap pipeline in .NET 2.0 - I want to do what a SoapExtension can do if you provide a custom SoapExtensionAttribute... but to do it for every SOAP call without having to add the extension attribute to dozens of WebMethods.

What I'm looking for is any extension point that lets me hook in as:

```
void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
```

without needing to individually decorate each WebMethod.  It's even fine if I have to only annotate the WebServices - I only have a few of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration property, [soapExtensionTypes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5e8e7kk(VS.71).aspx) that does this, but affects all web services covered by the .config (all of them in the same directory or a sub-directory as the .config)

Comment: Funnily enough, I was using that config section without understanding it.  I had read somewhere that it enabled SoapExtensions but thought that was a "validation" process that allowed the attribute to work.  But now I understand what it really does!  Thanks!